# MySQL pivoting not working as expected

Tags: mysql, pivot

**Schema:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `questions_tags`;
CREATE TABLE `questions_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
INSERT INTO `questions_tags` VALUES ('1', '1', '1');
INSERT INTO `questions_tags` VALUES ('2', '2', '1');
INSERT INTO `questions_tags` VALUES ('3', '3', '1');
INSERT INTO `questions_tags` VALUES ('4', '4', '1');
INSERT INTO `questions_tags` VALUES ('5', '5', '1');
INSERT INTO `questions_tags` VALUES ('6', '2', '2');
```

**Data:**

```
id  tag_id  question_id
1     1         1
2     2         1
3     3         1
4     4         1
5     5         1
6     2         2
```

**What I've tried:**

```
SELECT 
question_id,
CASE WHEN tag_id = 1 THEN 'TAG1' END AS FirstTag,
CASE WHEN tag_id = 2 THEN 'TAG2' END AS SecondTag,
CASE WHEN tag_id = 3 THEN 'TAG3' END AS ThirdTag,
CASE WHEN tag_id = 4 THEN 'TAG4' END AS FourthTag,
CASE WHEN tag_id = 5 THEN 'TAG5' END AS FifthTag
FROM questions_tags
GROUP BY question_id;
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Is there something that I misjudged about `Pivoting`? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably should define a unique key (question_id, tag_id). If it's not unique, then it does not make much sence, what you're going to do.

Comment: Actually I've a unique key on those two fields. For demonstration purpose I just made it look like simple. Thanks for your point @PaulSpiegel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregation on the case expressions.

```
SELECT 
question_id,
max(CASE WHEN tag_id = 1 THEN 'TAG1' END) AS FirstTag,
max(CASE WHEN tag_id = 2 THEN 'TAG2' END) AS SecondTag,
max(CASE WHEN tag_id = 3 THEN 'TAG3' END) AS ThirdTag,
max(CASE WHEN tag_id = 4 THEN 'TAG4' END) AS FourthTag,
max(CASE WHEN tag_id = 5 THEN 'TAG5' END) AS FifthTag
FROM questions_tags
GROUP BY question_id;
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain what's the role of `MAX` here?

Comment: @LordofTheRings By convention. Min works too (or group_concat(distinct...), etc.), but we tend to use max.

Comment: Thank you @Strawberry. But I want to know the insight story of using `MAX` here. Would you please explain?

Comment: @LordofTheRings Try it without the group by clause (and the aggregating functions). Lots of rows are returned, some of which are null. You need some rule for picking the not null ones.

Comment: @LordofTheRings, try `GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN tag_id = 1 THEN 'TAG1' ELSE 'NULL' END) AS FirstTag`. Then you will see the list of values `MAX`, `MIN` or `GROUP_CONCAT` would operate on. In this case i'm using `'NULL'` as string. But the original query is equal to `ELSE NULL`. `MAX`, `MIN` and `GROUP_CONCAT` will ignore every NULL "values" and will return NULL if every "value" in the list is NULL.

Comment: Thank you very much @PaulSpiegel. Your comment is worth an upvote!